# Github Desktop not displaying merge conflicts interface

Tags: github, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict, github-desktop

I've always used github desktop for viewing my merge conflicts and also solving them, but recently that beautiful and bright interface has suddenly disappeared and I just can't find a way to get it back and see my conflicts side by side.

I've already tried pretty much everything, and nothing seems to work.

Any thoughts?